# Continuity and openness proof

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I need some help proving the following theorem. My professor said that it was a "local" version of an important theorem:

Suppose f:X→Y and a ∈X. The function f is continuous at a if
and only if for every open set U containing b = f(a), there is an open set V containing a so that V ⊂ f−1(U).

What I know:

(i) Definition of continuity:Suppose X,Y are metric spaces, a ∈ X and f : X → Y. The function f is continuous at a if for every ε>0 there is a δ>0 such that if dX(a,x) < δ, then dY (f(a),f(x)) < ε.
If f is continuous at every point a ∈ X, then f is said to be continuous.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: For a similar question, check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551683/show-that-f-is-continuous/551688#551688

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For metric spaces $f$ is continuous at $a\in X$<=>for every $ε>0$ there is a $δ>0:$ for $x\in X $ that $d_{X}(x,a)<δ=>d_{Y}(f(x),f(a))<ε$.

=>)Let $U$ be an open neightbourhood of $f(a)$. Then for an $ε>0$ $(f(a)-ε,f(a)+ε)\subset U$ ($U$ is the union of such sets)we have an open neightbourhood of $f(a)$. Then for this $ε$ there is a $δ>0:d_{X}(x,a)<δ=>x\in B(a,δ)$ which is an open ball and thus we have $f(x)\in B(f(a),ε)$ for every $x\in B(a,δ)$.

<=)Let $ε>0$. Τhen $(f(a)-ε,f(a)+ε)$ is an open neightbourhood of $f(a)$ and there is an open set $V:f(V)\subset (f(a)-ε,f(a)+ε)$ that means that there is a $δ>0$ to do the job.